# Controller's variable is not reflecting on UI

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

On load of HTML page I call a function which is in angularjs controller (discussions()), which assigns value to a variable ($rootScope.name), later I will click a button on the same HTML page, this triggers a series of JavaScript functions and final one JS function calls same angularjs function by using this command

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('loadDiscussions')).scope().discussions();
```

Though this funtion will be called but im not seeing any value on UI. I think the scope of that variable is missing or something.

Note: On page load i see the value on UI but on clicking the button im not seeing any value.

Comment: Sorry, i did not mention it. But im using jQuery too to call angularjs function (I tried using JS but failed).. Is there any wrong..?

Comment: Sorry Regent, I'm out of world i guess.. here jQuery is nothing to do..

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I assume that the code is run outside the digest cycle of angularjs. Angularjs uses a digest cycle to run the different watches which is responsible for updating the UI and calling other watch handlers etc. Since your code is not running inside a digest cycle angularjs is unaware about the changes done to the scope variables so the digest cycle is not triggered thus the UI is not updated.

```
var $scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('loadDiscussions')).scope();
$scope.discussions();
if (!$scope.$$phase) {
    $scope.$apply()
}
```

If you can explain why you want to access the scope outside of the angular control and call the method, we might be able to give a better solution

- [$digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest)
- [Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Comment: Wouldn't `.$apply()` be a better option?

Comment: @techouse yes... don't know why I called $digest

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Actully im displaying<div> <p>{{name}}</p></div> on page load. It contains a button which will make an ajax call to fetch values to fill in <h> element inside this <div>. Later again i need to call angularjs to display something like this <div> <p>{{name}}</p><h>{{link}}<h></div>